# Scatter plot only lines that meet the condition in a specific column

Tags: python, python-3.x, colors, scatter-plot

I would like to scatter plot a number of stations from a txt file to a map, using cartopy:

```
def ReadData(FileName,typee,delimee):
    return np.genfromtxt(FileName, dtype=typee, delimiter=delimee, encoding='latin-1')

MyTypes = ("|U11","float","float","float","|U1","|U2","|U1","|U29")
MyDelimiters = [11,9,10,7,1,2,1,29] # station ID, lat, lon (-180 to 180), elevation (m), blank, Country code, blank, Name
RawData = ReadData(stations.txt,MyTypes,MyDelimiters)
```

stations.txt:

```
01001099999  70.9330   -8.6670    9.0 NO JAN MAYEN(NOR-NAVY)           0100109
01001599999  61.3830    5.8670  327.0 NO BRINGELAND                    0100159
01003099999  77.0000   15.5000   12.0 NO HORNSUND                      0100309
01008099999  78.2460   15.4660   26.8 SV LONGYEAR                      0100809
01010099999  69.2930   16.1440   13.1 NO ANDOYA                        0101009
```

2nd column represents the latitudes, 3rd column the longitudes, 4th column the elevation.

```
StationListID  = np.array(RawData['f0'])
StationListLat  = np.array(RawData['f1'])
StationListLon  = np.array(RawData['f2'])
StationListElev = np.array(RawData['f3'])
```

I use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as crs

plt.scatter(x=StationListLon, y=StationListLat,
                color="dodgerblue",
                s=1,
                alpha=0.5,
                transform=crs.PlateCarree())
```

If the elevation < 0, I would like to have black dots, for > 5 green, for > 10 red and for > 15 blue dots. Where do I set the if conditions or group the lines?

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: Many thanks for your help, Ruthger! Your code works, yes. I am reading data in via `RawData = ReadData(InList,MyTypes,MyDelimiters)` and `RawData['colors'] = pd.cut(RawData['f3'], bins=cut_bins, labels=color_labels)` gives me `ValueError: no field of name colors`.

Comment: It's difficult to see what is going on. Could you update your question and add all the steps that you take and show what `RawData.head()` gives after each step?

Comment: Maybe there's the error alread: `RawData.head()` right after `StationListElev = np.array(RawData['f3'])` gives me `*** AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'head'`. My RawData look like this, if I don't add x f1 f2 f3 stations to the first line of my ASCII file: `[('01001099999', 70.933,  -8.667,   9. , ' ', 'NO', ' ', 'JAN MAYEN(NOR-NAVY)          ')
 ...
 ("''''\n",    nan,     nan,   nan, '', '', '', '')]`

Comment: What does `type(RawData)` give you directly after `ReadData` and once again after `StationListElev = np.array(RawData['f3'])`?

Comment: It was a numpy.ndarray, which I converted then `RawData = pd.DataFrame(RawData)` to `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`. Now, the ValueError is solved, but `c=RawData['colors']` returns `ValueError: c of shape (4487,) not acceptable as a color sequence for x with size 4487, y with size 4487`. That's the length of my ASCII file.

Comment: What is `RawData['colors'].value_counts()` giving?

Comment: `blue      2782
green      293
yellow     274
red        192
black       26
Name: colors, dtype: int64`; That's only 3567, not 4487. Changing `cut_bins = [-2000, 0, 5, 10, 15, 9000]` is not making it better.

Comment: It works! I had added """ as the last line of my text file; after deleting that, all works fine. Many thanks for your help, Ruthger! Very much appreciated!

Comment: It's my pleasure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules and data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import io

RawData = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
x f1 f2 f3 stations
01001099999 70.9330 -8.6670 9.0 NOJANMAYEN(NOR-NAVY) 
01001599999 61.3830 5.8670 327.0 NOBRINGELAND          
01003099999 77.0000 15.5000 12.0 NOHORNSUND             
01008099999 78.2460 15.4660 26.8 SVLONGYEAR             
01010099999 69.2930 16.1440 13.1 NOANDOYA
"""), sep="\s", engine="python")

StationListLat  = np.array(RawData['f1'])
StationListLon  = np.array(RawData['f2'])
StationListElev = np.array(RawData['f3'])
```

You could first make labels that signify the colors using `pd.cut`.

```
color_labels = ['black', 'yellow', 'green', 'red', 'blue']
cut_bins = [-500, 0, 5, 10, 15, 500]
RawData['colors'] = pd.cut(RawData['f3'], bins=cut_bins, labels=color_labels)
```

Then you could use these labels to display the colors of the dots. Note that you do not have a color for values inbetween 0 and 5, I just gave it the color yellow.
As you see, I left the crs part out, if I am not mistaken it is not directly relevant for this problem.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(x=StationListLon, y=StationListLat,
            color=RawData['colors'],
            s=20,
            alpha=0.5)
```